Let $f(x)=x^2-kx$ and $g(x)=x^3-kx $, $k \in\mathbb R$ are two real functions such that for a rational number $a,$ $f(a),g(a)$ are both rational
Let $f(x)=x^2-kx$ and $g(x)=x^3-kx$ , $k\in \mathbb R$ are two real values functions such that for a rational number alpha both the functions are rational
Then find least positive integral value of k and least positive value of k .
I think least integral should be 1 as sum , diff , multiplication, division of Rationals are Rationals and least positive should be 0+. But the answers are 2 and 1.33 resp . Please Help

Welcome to math SE. Have a look at mathjax.

Not following.  If $k\in \mathbb Q$, isn't the condition satisfied?

I agree with your $1$, and understand your $0^+$ (though I'd rather say there is no least positive value). Can you please include an image of the question and the answer?
